we need a "linux" tag
I asked Can I use the WeDo USB hub with normal Linux distributions? and tagged it with linux, which was subsequently removed along with the comment "I don't think we need a linux tag".  Another user asked https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/698.  While I don't expect Linux-only users to be in the majority here, I do think that linux would be useful for those who are looking for Linux+Lego information.
As another example, LPub doesn't natively support Linux, but I've ported it to Linux.  (Published on my blog.)
So I think there is room for questions that are directly related to Linux but Lego-centric here.  Given that, I think linux would be useful.
What say you?

I think the questions on which a linux tag would be helpful are the kind of questions which are actually borderline for this site. Sure, they are about LEGO software, but if the answer is going to be along the lines of how to install and run a virtual machine or whatever, then maybe whether the question is asked on the right site is debatable.
Anyway, I don't mind the questions that much, but I'm pretty much against any OS-specific or computer-specific tag. software should be more than enough. AT the moment, anyway.

I think single general software will be enough for the first time.

Yeah, and besides that, if you want to look for question that involve a certain OS, just type something like "windows" in the search and you immediately get your results, which renders OS tags useless.

I'm not convinced that we do need a Linux tag for a couple of reasons:

We'll almost invariably end up with Windows and Mac tags as well, and then someone will argue that they need an Ubuntu one too "How do I run LPub under Ubuntu?"
I'm not convinced that we'll really have enough questions that are specifically about Linux related issues - the search works fairly well to find questions and answers with Linux in them, and really I'd rather see the tags here related to the software packages in question, rather than the host OS.

If someone has a question about how to generate a manual in LPub it shouldn't matter whether it's the Linux version or a Windows one really.
However, I'm happy to see what the rest of the community thinks, and go with the direction.

Creating instructions in LPub is not OS-specific, but running LPub on Linux is, particularly since you'd have to apply patches.  The latter being what I was trying reference in my example.

Yep, I realise that it's the "running LPub" aspect that you were getting at - what I meant was that people might well tag a question about creating instructions in LPub and tag that "linux" when it should really just be "lpub". Like I say, if we end up with enough questions that are truly improved by having the Linux tag (or Windows or Macintosh) then great :)
